# How do I make sure WinSock sends to all clients?

Tags: sockets, vb6, winsock

I have written a vb6 game to allow 4 players to play a card game.
One of the players will host the game and the others will join.

I used a socket array to join all of the other players with the host socket

Everything went smooth and I am able to send messages from each player to the rest of the players, from host to guests and vice versa

However, during the game, one player would "tell" the host that a card is chosen. The host will then send the same message to each of the clients connected to the socket array like this

```
For i=1 to 3
    Me.SocketArray(i).SendData player.selectedCard
    DoEvents
Next
```

but for some reason, one of the player never receives the message. Although the same player did receive messages before this point, and possible will receive other messages later.

So there is a Syncing problem with what was send and what was not.
I looked for answers everywhere, and some suggested to use `DoEvents` more often to force the winsock to send the data immediately.

I then thought of implementing an inbox for each player in which each player must reply with an acknowledgment of the received message, and the host will not send any more messages until the arrival of acknowledgement, but that made the game slower and I had the same problem I had before, but this time it's not the messages that got lost, it's the acknowledgment.

The number 1 reason I think I am having all of this is that the Winsock control sometimes sends incomplete messages (one character missing) and that will create a mess, because I need every character at the other end, otherwise the message is useless.

How can I make sure that whenever the host sends a message, all the other guests receive ALL of it intact?

Comment: What protocol/s are you using for your messages?  Winsock TCP does not lose bytes - if it did, millions of developers/users would know about it pretty quick!  DoEvents is not likely to make much difference - the Windows network stack is a complex, multiThreaded OS subsystem and doesn't really care how promptly you process messages in your app.

Comment: I am using the default settings for the Winsock control. TCP. When I debug the code, (running multiple instances of the same code on one machine) I get all the messages intact, but when I distribute the code over multiple machines, there is always one missing character occasionally.

Comment: Well, if your messages are short, you should set the TCP_NODELAY socket option to disable the Nagle algorithm.  Also, what protocol do you use to define your messages?  Are they text with a CRLF at the end, SOH/ETX or some other message-delimiting protocol?

Comment: Indeed these are short text messages, but I never considered terminating the messages with vbCrLf because some of the messages are actually chat text by the players and sometimes the text includes vbCrLf already. I will check the algorithm disabling option. Thanks +1

Comment: If there are mixed text/chat and other messages, how do you tell them apart?

Comment: I simply begin each message with a certain HEADER to distinguish each message kind. The problem is sometimes the header arrives incomplete. For example, a header like "P1_PLAY_CARD:04R" means player 1 just selected a card with the value 4 and color red. another message might be "P2_SAYS:[that's cheating!!!]" is just a chat message from Player 2,, and so on

Comment: Just a note that TCP is a stream protocol, not a packet protocol.  This means that its possible to apparently 'lose' characters.  Are you sure that they don't appear in front of the next message.  How do you parse incoming messages?  Do you look for the 'P' header char?  Might you be skipping over the missing char?

Comment: As I said, when all of the players are on the same machine (opening 4 copies of the application) everything runs without any problems, but when the application is run on 4 different machines, some of the messages arrive missing some characters. I logged all messages on all 4 players machine, and when the message is short one character, this character does not come in the next message.

Comment: You are likely to see differences when you go from all-on-one-machine to multiple machines as some of the sockets stack is bypassed on the same machine.  That said, TCP provides some guarantees.  You could always try sending a NOP message after each other message to see what happens.  eg 'Px_NOP'

Comment: I will consider that. Thanks @quamarana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoEvents() calls are hazardous in the wrong hands.

What you probably have going on is the assumption of "magic" message framing, a failure to buffer and parse messages from inbound data streams, and reentrant calls to your DataArrival handler because you are calling DoEvents().

Nagle could be an issue as well but it should result in responsiveness problems and not apparent data loss.

This same issue has been asked about and answered innumerable times over the last decade.